# How to calculate date of most recent event for an event which happens every X multiple date components?

Tags: date, cocoa, nscalendar

Say I have a recurring event, which happens every X components, where 'components' is a `DateComponents` with more than one unit defined, such as 'every three days and two hours' or 'every other year and a day'.

> **Example**
>
> - Date of first event: `2015-02-27`
> - Interval between events: `2 years, 1 day` (a.k.a. 'every other year and a day')

Calculating the list of next events from the initial event is fairly trivial, one only needs to create a `Date` of the initial event and a `DateComponents` describing the recurring amount, and you can trivially find the nth date:

```swift
let calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)

let initialEventDate = calendar.date(from: DateComponents(year: 2015, month: 02, day: 27))!
let eventInterval = DateComponents(year: 2, day: 1)

// Returns the date of the nth event
let eventDate = { (n: Int) -> Date in
    return calendar.date(byAdding: eventInterval * n, to: initialEventDate)!
}
```

*Note that the above uses a custom operator, `*`, to multiply all components with a given integer.*

The above returns just what I want:

> - 0 → 2015-02-27
> - 1 → 2017-02-28
> - 2 → 2019-03-01
> - 3 → 2021-03-02
>
> *Et cetera*

The question is, how do I find the date of the last event given some other date? Or phrased another way, how do I implement this in reverse (i.e. to find *n* for the given date)?

For example, if I had the date `2017-06-21`, then *n* is some number between 1 and 2, though in my case I'm only really interested in rounding down *n* to find the date of the last event. It is however important that I'm able to get a negative value for *n* if the given date is before the event start date, as if the event has been happening since forever and the event start date is just an 'example' date to define the offset.

Initially I thought of calculating the number of components between the given date and the initial event date (only asking for the components which are part of the interval definition) and diving the resulting components by those in the interval definition and rounding down, but it soon became clear that this wouldn't work.

The only other way I can think of doing it is by guessing and checking. Is there a better way using Apple's date functionality?

Comment: How do you check after guessing? I would add the interval in a loop until the date is passed.

Comment: Yeah, not very efficient though!